# Pass a parameter to a SQL Server trigger

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to pass a parameter from a Session value in C# to my Trigger in SQL Server.
Is it possible for me to do that?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by pass it to a sql trigger? What are you trying to do?

Comment: i am creating an audit trail and I want to pass the username of the logged in user to a parameter and insert it to my audit table

Answer (score 0):

A trigger can't accept parameters, Instead, you can use a function or stored procedure. Or if you want the trigger to work based on some parameters or values from your session, try this

- Add a column to your table which will store the value from the session
- Now insert or update the value from your session to this new columns
- You can read the value inside the trigger from this column and do your calculations accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Please and always mention the specific version and edition of sql server you are using. Functionality varies according to these facts; you can avoid a lot of misdirection and confusion by including that information.

Next, provide context for your questions. Does your application/architecture use a common login/user to access the database? If not, try [user_name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/user-name-transact-sql) or one of the related functions. If it does use a common identity, then you will need to provide that information prior to executing the statement that fires the trigger. In older versions you use context_info; newer ones can use [session_context](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4094/phase-out-contextinfo-in-sql-server-2016-with-sessioncontext/).

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little late, but had the same kind of problem last week. I used the answer from this question:

[How to add custom attributes to SQL connection string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581002/how-to-add-custom-attributes-to-sql-connection-string)

aka, used the ApplicationName attribute in c# and used the APP_NAME() in sql, as we did not use this variabel anywhere.

Your question, however seems like you could use the ORIGINAL_LOGIN() in sql, if it is an SQL user you want to save.

You could also, if you need the APP_NAME somewhere else, go with substringing the APP_NAME so that the first 100 bytes are for the application name and the rest is for a user. It is dirty and requires some manual labor but will do the job.