# Is there a way to execute a SQL command on a ADO.NET connection like the SQLCMD -q option?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net

We have multiple applications writing to our MS SQL 2008 R2 database and there is a need to capture information about these applications during these writes. The database code (triggers, stored procedures etc) are under my control and can be modified but not the application code.

I am leaning towards using `CONTEXT_INFO` to store application specific information and retrieving it in the  triggers. The 1M$ question is "How can I get the applications to set the `CONTEXT_INFO` if they are loath to change application code ?".

I DO have access to the connection strings that these applications use as these reside in config files.

I was not able to find any properties on the connection string that I can use to set `CONTEXT_INFO` (or execute any TSQL at initialization). Basically I was hoping to simulate the behaviour of `SQLCMD -q` option e.g `SQLCMD -q "SET CONTEXT_INFO 0x1244"`.

Is there any way to simulate this behavior in ADO.NET via configuration ? Or a different way to do this ? Any pointers appreciated.

If there is no way this can be done, I can take the message back and tell "management" that application code has to be changed.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25581002/how-to-add-custom-attributes-to-sql-connection-string. App changes are needed for anything beyond `APP_NAME()`.

Comment: Thanks Dan. The AppName & HostName are already taken by the applications.So I cannot use these